# How to add a cell with two buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to have two buttons as the first row and the rest of the rows as it is shown in the following picture (I apologize for the flipped picture):

[image]

I know how to put two buttons in a cell, like so: [image]

And use the following code to add the first cell to my tableview like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        //Configure the first cell with the two buttons
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = cathyList[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

My logic allows me to have two buttons as the first row cell but I don't know how to make the buttons big and square like the ones that are shown here. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest, looking at the following search. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UIButton+Custom it will help you achieve what you want. Some will be Obj-C but you will be able to use the same logic.

Comment: Add your button on table header view. First of all, drag an empty UIView between Navigation bar and Prototype cell. That view will now work as your table header. Than in that view add those buttons.

Comment: You can set this buttons in tableview's header view.

Comment: The better way is add that two button in table's header view instead of adding it in first cell. And by setting "edge" of title and image of button you can customize your button.

Comment: Ahh... I see thank you. I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You format your button as what you want on Storyboard. I suggest 2 options you can get this:

- You can add image and title on button and use `Edge` property to achieve this. Look at this: [image]

This way is hard to achieve what you need, you have to make sure your icon has the right size, and it's not dynamic.

- The second way is easier and more dynamic. But maybe not the best solution. I usually use this way.

[image]

You add an image (show your icon), a label (your title) and embed them in a view. Then add a button stretch all the view. Connect this button to action and use it as usual.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your response @truongky. I really appreciate the time and effort that you took to answer my question. And I think combining your answer and the suggestions in the comments will enable me to achieve the desired outcome. Thank you again! :) And Merry Christmas!!!